# How can I pass dynamic variables to Scripts via Asset Manager

Tags: grav

I want to add some script to Grav using some parameters.

```
{% do assets.addInlineJs('var imageurl = "'.{{ url('theme://images/logo.svg') }}.'";', 99) %}
```

This and some other things like

```
{% do assets.addInlineJs('var imageurl = "' . url("theme://images/logo.svg") . '";', 99) %}
```

do not work. What am I missing? I want to use an imagepath from the theme to pass to the script.

Comment: Did you got this working? I'm having the same issues trying to pass parameters to a function using inlinejs

Comment: No, I haven't. It may be a possible using the Assets Plugin (https://github.com/getgrav/grav-plugin-assets) but I have not tested it yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To concatenate strings in Twig, you need to use ~ not .

```
{% do assets.addInlineJs('var imageurl = "' ~ url("theme://images/logo.svg") ~ '";', 99) %}
```

Sample result:

```
var imageurl = "/user/themes/my-theme/images/logo.svg";
```

Comment: Thanks, I have solved it with a static script at last, but now I know for the future.